# List in HTTP request

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have an HTTP POST request with the following variables: "UnicodeMultiDict: ... (u'ids[]', u'568236498'), (u'ids[]', u'528900768')". It seems like it is a list, so how can I retireve these variables? When I use self.request.POST.get('ids[]') it only returns the first element.

I am using the webapp framework.

Thanks,

Joel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.request.POST.getall('ids[]')` - see http://pythonpaste.org/webob/modules/webob.html#webob.multidict.MultiDict